# Where can we find statistics about the site's progress through beta?

Tags: feature-request, beta, meta

It would be useful to know what needs work at-a-click.  Where can we read, gather, and/or store such information?

It appears that we're moving from the answer-the-seeded-questions stage to another, less purpose-driven stage.  There are a lot of questions with submissions but no answers - [Just go to the list, back a few days, and scroll through.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions?page=3&sort=newest)  Lots of questions haven't seen activity since the first hours they were asked, and **most** don't have answers!  That's bad for a beta, right?  Or, do we want to leave questions open for new answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get some basic statistics at the **Area51 site**:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2148/tex-latex-and-friends

As for now:

> **169 questions**
>
> **436 answers**
>
> **92% answered**
>
> **212 users**
>
> **3,700 views/day**

We've been 3 days in **closed beta**. So far, we've done 56 questions/day and 145 answers/day. I don't know if these values are promising or not for a site at the beta stage like this one. The only way I can imagine to interpret this values is comparing them to other sites in **Area 51**. Let's take a look at **[Web Applications](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications)**, which is one of the most successful SE sites:

> 1,319 questions
>
> 3,464 answers
>
> 93% answered
>
> 3,310 users
>
> 2,340 views/day

They've already been 29 days in **open beta**, which translates to 45 questions/day and 119 answers/day. By this data, it seems we're doing a little better than our competitors :P. I expect that the number of new questions and answers per day will slow down in the next few days.

Answer (score 2):

Quick stats (as of 7/29), compiled by hand :P

### Users:

Total: 105
With >101 rep: 56
Committed: 376
Active in the past 48 hours: ???

This is sad - I thought committing meant more than this.  Is there any way to email-blast the committers list again, or would that not be profitable?

### Questions:

Total: 169
Total > 48 hours old: 118
With zero upvoted answers: 13
With zero upvoted answers, > 48 hours old: 8
Without a selected answer: 108 (*1)
Jul 26: 50
Jul 27: 29
Jul 28: 14
Jul 29: 15

This gives an asked/answered percentage of a blazing 33% for questions over 2 days old.  That is simply unacceptable for a site to be useful. It appears that many of the questioners are high-ranking, so I'll request that everyone who reads this goes to their user page and check all of their questions for answers, and accept one (the check mark under the voting arrows :) if it's acceptable!

### Tags:

Total: 231
With >1 use:  81 (*2)
With >2 uses: 39

### Badges:

(Less important than the above...)

Total badges awarded:
Bronze: 253
Silver: 0
Gold: 0
Badges awarded to at least one user:
Bronze: 14
Silver: 0
Gold: 0

---

Hope that this helps us get some perspective on the work that's left to be done at the moment!  However, a page where we could view this would be much better.  Something like the [bootstrap counter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/bootstrap).

*1 - IMO, anything over 2 days old should either be bumped because the existing answers are insufficient, or have an answer selected. Please comment.
*2 - No tags are used only once.  This is weird.

Comment: Community wiki so that we can keep these stats updated as necessary.  Please note which stats you updated if you didn't update all of them!  Hopefully this will be obsolete soon.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to interpret those statistics, in particular whether they are good or bad.  However, I would sound one note of warning to those who want to put some weight on it: it is the middle of the summer holidays when academics (probably one of our larger arenas) all zoom off round conferences and beaches and probably don't have much time for asking and answering questions!

Comment: Hard to say about 'blasting' the committers, but a reminder of some sort probably wouldn't be a bad idea.  I know that if I hadn't already been somewhat active over the last few days and received a reminder now, I personally wouldn't consider it spam... After all, not only did I sign up, but actually committed to being here, so I could hardly consider a reminder to be unsolicited.  Maybe now that there's a little more to the site a few people who checked it out initially then didn't come back will be more likely to stay this time.